# Track Views on SQL Server 

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, linq

I got a table in SQL Server which keeps updated almost every second from another software (Stock Prices).

I need to create a WPF Application with a grid that shows a View from SQL Server. (view is just a complex query with inner joins on the stock table and some other tables).

But since the View keeps updated, I can't really do `SqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds)` every second.

So far; I've heard about the following techniques..

- SQL-Dependency
- Push Subscription combined with Bindable-LINQ
- SQL StreamInsight.
- SQLstream.com

Which one is the proper way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we do:

- Using triggers, write the affected
  entity ids to a push notification
  queue table
- Using SQL service broker, send notifications from the queue table to a notification server to which all end clients are connected
- Distribute push notification events for batches of affected entityids from the notification server to all connected clients
- The client re-enquires against the view for the affected entities and updates the UI accordingly (remove any deleted, update any changed, insert any new)

It works well.

Comment: Thank you very much but I didn't quite understand the concepts of "queue table" and "push notification events for batches".

Comment: By queue table I simply meant a table that holds the entity types and Ids of records that have been inserted, updated or deleted - until such time as these are flushed out to your notification server.  

For performance reasons, it is probably a good idea to have the notification server do some buffering, and send notifications for batches of entities in one go rather than as soon as they are received.

Comment: I need to say this, this was not actually a solution, because you can't actually write AfterTriggers for Views.

Comment: @Stylus - of course not. The triggers are placed on the underlying tables.

Answer (score 0):

StreamInsight is a good start but you are looking at it the wrong way. 
Build a StreamInsight input adapter to read the stock feeds. You can do more than just read them, too. You can do analysis and other processing on them as well ... on the fly. From there, you would have an output adapter going to SQL Server and a output adapter publishing a WCF Duplex Service or a multicast service (some sort of network push publishing service) and have your client subscribe to it. If you don't need to store the quotes, you don't need to use Sql Server at all. 
One work of caution - depending on how much data you have coming in, you could possible overwhelm your Sql Server and/or your client. StreamInsight can handle FAR more data than either of them can - it's all in memory (no disk).